# Proof that Bellman Optimality Operator converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, operator-theory, contraction-operator

Let $T^*$ be the Bellman Optimality Operator defined as follow:

$$(T^*Q)(s,a) = R(s,a) + \gamma \max_{a' \in A} \sum_{s' \in S} P(s'|s,a)Q(s',a')$$

with $0 \leq P(s'|s,a) \leq 1$ and $\sum_{s' \in S} P(s'|s,a) = 1$.

I can proove that $T^*$ is a max-norm contraction, in other word (if I get it correctly)

$$\lVert T^*Q - T^*Q'\rVert \leq \lVert Q - Q'\rVert $$

And in this way, it is possible to say that:

$$\lVert Q_{t+2} - Q_{t+1}\rVert \leq \lVert Q_{t+1} - Q_{t}\rVert$$

provided that

$$Q_{t+1} = T^*Q_{t}$$

In this way I can only show that, iterating over the bellman operator, the difference between $Q_{t+1}$ and $Q_t$ get lower (in module), but it doesn't mean that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \lVert Q_{t+1} - Q_t \rVert = 0$.
And I'm interested in showing this last sentence.

P.S. $Q_0 = 0$

Comment: Your first equation does not seem correct (e.g., what is $a^\prime$?). Also, $\Vert T^* Q - T^* Q^\prime \Vert \leq \Vert Q - Q^\prime \Vert$ is not usually what we call a contraction, it is a nonexpansion.

Comment: Okay, you are right. it was $max_{a' \in A}$. I'll correct it. So.. As far as I know, Bellman operator should be a max-norm contraction, how can I provide it? and how can I provide that $|Q_{t+1}-Q_t|$ tends to 0 for high t?

Comment: If it is contractive, there exists a unique solution. However, not all Bellman problems are contractive (e.g., a paper of mine https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03928.pdf considers nonexpansive problems). Do you know anything about the transition probabilities?

Comment: If you're willing to slug through it, the paper I linked you to has an answer to your question in a very general setting in which the state space is finite (which I assume is your setting). It should also extend to the countable case (within reason) as well.

Comment: I'll try to read through, but at first impression I'm not sure that I have the mathematical competence to understand it, and also, as far as I can see, it is talking about Policy Iteration, and actually the bellman equation is different from the one that I wrote. The bellman equation above is used in FQI algorithm, and it requires Q=0 in the first step, while in Policy iteration I can start from any V